# Ext Js Grid, Issue in summing of column value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs-grid

I'm using Ext Js v6.2 Grid, In my application, I have three columns **Charges, Rate & Amount** Here I want to get all the value of **third column [AMOUNT]** & Sum it up.

I used Ext Js Function **"var mysum = gridStore.getStore().sum('amount');"**

I'm getting the sumvalue If value given in all row of the column, **but If I skip one row, sumvalue doesn't addup** Here's my code, please correct my code if I'm wrong, I've searched in documentation and other stuff it doesn't help.please solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
   listeners: {
              element: 'el',
              keypress: function(form, e,rowIndex,selModel, record, index, options, args){
              var Input= document.getElementById(e.id).value;
              var selectedRecord1 = gridStore.getSelection()[0];
              rowindex2 = gridStore.store.indexOf(selectedRecord1);
              var models = gridStore.getStore().getRange();
              models[rowindex2].set("amount", Input); 
              var mysum = gridStore.getStore().sum('amount');
              alert(mysum);

   }
```

[image: AMOUNT SUM INCORRECTLY]

[image: AMOUNT SUM CORRECTLY]

Comment: So what's your issue.. if any row doesnt have value then it shows incorrect value or any other issue?

Comment: @yogendarji yes exactly, if any row doesn't have value then it shows incorrect value, thats my problem.

Comment: There are number of issues, I think. First change `keypress` to `keyup` as you are setting value before it's on textfield. second, I doubt you're not clean up store for second time use. if you make any fiddle then can help you more.